# Stream media stops at 2Mb in Chrome, but Not MS Edge?

Tags: audio-streaming

investigating an interesting IE/Chrome thing I think.   So, we have a streaming audio service that can queue up audio files.  On average, the audio is less than 2Mb but occasionally we run across one that is slightly larger.   Our clients started to complain that our audio was stalling out.

So, we fired up an azure vm.   Figured that'd be a good neutral comparison, same firewall, same settings, everything.

This happens to be  a Windows 10 VM.  Nothing special about it.

So, in Edge, everything works fine.  We can stream audio of any size without any problem.

In Chrome though, they all stop at 2Mb.

I doubt it has anything to do with our service (it works fine in Edge, but not chrome).

If it was a network framing issue, I would expect it to affect both, it doesn't.

If it were virus protection then I'd expect it to be an issue for both.   (And for grins and giggles, I fired up a VM that didn't have antivirus, no difference).

I haven't tried firefox on it yet to see.

Anybody got any ideas of what it might be?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to a partial content request method.....  I found the answer here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/23/asp-net-web-api-and-http-byte-range-support/

It ended up being all of about 10 lines of code I had to add